# ng-bootstrap typeahead - Error with showing results

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to add ng-bootstrap typeahead to an existing project. I simply added the demo code from the [ng-bootstrap example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples). (labelled API
Simple Typeahead)

When typing in a value the drop down box appears but with no values, although i can highlight a line and clicking the highlighted section fills the text box with the correct value.

It's almost as if the text results are not being written out.

the HTML shows this :

```
<button class="dropdown-item" role="option" type="button">
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
}-->
      <ngb-highlight _nghost-c2=""><!----></ngb-highlight>

      </button>
```

and chrome debug tools shows this :

```
ERROR TypeError: _v.context.formatter is not a function
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NgbTypeaheadWindow.html:3)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.js?v=1IRb52vH45mb7Eaa5E54mqzy79t-CsOu8zFORpABXoI:17823)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js?v=1IRb52vH45mb7Eaa5E54mqzy79t-CsOu8zFORpABXoI:17003)
at callViewAction (vendor.js?v=1IRb52vH45mb7Eaa5E54mqzy79t-CsOu8zFORpABXoI:17368)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (vendor.js?v=1IRb52vH45mb7Eaa5E54mqzy79t-CsOu8zFORpABXoI:17326)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js?v=1IRb52vH45mb7Eaa5E54mqzy79t-CsOu8zFORpABXoI:17004)
at callViewAction (vendor.js?v=1IRb52vH45mb7Eaa5E54mqzy79t-CsOu8zFORpABXoI:17368)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (vendor.js?v=1IRb52vH45mb7Eaa5E54mqzy79t-CsOu8zFORpABXoI:17326)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js?v=1IRb52vH45mb7Eaa5E54mqzy79t-CsOu8zFORpABXoI:17004)
at callViewAction (vendor.js?v=1IRb52vH45mb7Eaa5E54mqzy79t-CsOu8zFORpABXoI:17368)
```

and highlights the following:

```
<ngb-highlight [result]="formatter(result)" [term]="term"></ngb-highlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have a formatter function in your Typescript file:

```
formatter = (result: string) => result.toUpperCase();
```